# PHP no muestra los datos de la tabla

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, tablas

**Hola a todos!**

Mi código php no me muestra los datos de la tabla que estoy solicitando.
Quiero hacer un sistema de búsqueda de recursos (imágenes, vectores, archivos, etc.) por categoría y que me muestre cada fila en una imagen y el nombre del archivo.

El problema es que al darle click al botón, no sucede nada.

Acá el código:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Inter', arial;
}
```

```html
<?php
  session_start();
  $ci = $_SESSION['ci'];
  // Controlo si el usuario ya está logueado en el sistema.
  if(isset($_SESSION['ci'])){
      
  }else{
    // Si no está logueado lo redireccion a la página de login.
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
    header("Location: login?error=nr"); 
  }$link = new mysqli("blabla", "blabla", "blabla", "blabla");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page" align="center">
            <p style="font-size: 250%; margin-bottom: 3px"><i class="fas fa-file-`introducir el código aquí`alt"></i>&nbsp;Recursos</p>
            <form name="ctgform" method="post">
                <label style="font-size: 120%; margin-top: 3px" for="category"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i>&nbsp;Categoría:</label>
                <select name="category" class="select">
                    <option default disabled>Seleccionar</option>
                    <option value="diseno">Diseño</option>
                    <option value="transmisiones">Transmisiones</option>
                    <option value="foto">Fotografía</option>
                    <option value="bancoimg">Banco de imágenes</option>
                    <option value="docs">Documentos</option>
                </select>
                <button class="pgbutton" type="submit" name="buscar" style="font-size: 100%"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Buscar</button>
            </form>
            <? if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
                $categoria = $_POST['category'];
                    if ($categoria == "transmisiones") {
                    foreach ($link->query("SELECT * FROM a_recursos WHERE categoria='transmisiones'") as $row ) { 
                            echo "<img src='".$row['link']."'>";
                            echo $row['nombre'];
                        }
                }
            } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: De antemano hay un error, suponiendo que `$link` sea una instancia de [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php), deberías obtener las **filas** como `Array` para poder usarlas e iterar sobre ellas, por ejemplo con `$rows = $link->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Comment: @Josbert No entiendo tu respuesta, ¿donde pongo la linea? Es que llevo poco tiempo con PHP y MySQL.

Comment: No te preocupes te explico, deberías poner eso antes del `foreach`, (*ejecutando también la **consulta** fuera de este*) y después de haber hecho tu consulta; e iteras la variable `$rows` en cambio de tu consulta en crudo `foreach($rows as $row)`

Comment: Así?  `$rows = $link->fetch_all("SELECT * FROM a_recursos WHERE categoria='transmisiones'"); foreach ($rows as $row) { `

Comment: Nono, **primero** esto: `$link->query("SELECT * FROM a_recursos WHERE categoria='transmisiones'");`, **segundo** esto:  `$rows = $link->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`, **tercero** esto: `foreach ($rows as $row){ ...`

Comment: @Josbert Sigue sin funcionar... Cuando le doy click al botón se hace más larga la página pero no muestra nada.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, claro tu código tiene algunos errores, como dije *De antemano hay un error* pero no es el único que veo, dejare una respuesta de lo que veo allí. Tal vez hayan mas errores que aquí no puedo ver, pero de igual manera responderé esto. Por favor, edita y agrega también el código donde inicias tu conexión con la **DDBB**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien como te decía, tienes varios errores por los cuales tu código no esta funcionando, empezando por el que te menciono en los comentarios:

**Suponiendo** que estés usando la extensión [**mysqli**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.examples-basic.php) de **PHP** *(Cosa que no se realmente)* estas iterando de manera incorrecta los resultados de la consulta, deberías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

1. Abrir la conexión con tu base de datos, cosa que no veo y claro **es muy importante**.
2. También deberías verificar si hay errores en la conexión.
3. Ejecutar tu consulta.
4. Pasar tu consulta a un `Array`
5. Plasmar lo que necesites en tu **html**

```php
<form name="ctgform" method="post">
    <label style="font-size: 120%; margin-top: 3px" for="category"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i>&nbsp;Categoría:</label>
    <select name="category" class="select">
        <option default disabled>Seleccionar</option>
        <option value="diseno">Diseño</option>
        <option value="transmisiones">Transmisiones</option>
        <option value="foto">Fotografía</option>
        <option value="bancoimg">Banco de imágenes</option>
        <option value="docs">Documentos</option>
    </select>
    <button class="pgbutton" type="submit" name="buscar" value="Enviar" style="font-size: 100%"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Buscar</button>
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
    // Supongamos que abres tu conexión
    $link = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'tu_base_de_datos');

    $categoria = $_POST['category'];
    if ($categoria == "transmisiones") {
        // Ejecutas tu consulta
        $query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM a_recursos WHERE categoria='transmisiones'");

        // Pasas todas las filas obtenidas a Array asociativo        
        $rows = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        foreach ($rows as $row ) { 
            echo "<img src='".$row['link']."'>";
            echo $row['nombre'];
        }
    }
} ?>
```

**Otros de los errores que note son:**

- Tu condición `if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) { ...` nunca se cumplirá, porque tu `<button>` no tiene un `value`, como se lo dí aquí:

```html
<button class="pgbutton" type="submit" name="buscar" value="Enviar" style="font-size: 100%"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Buscar</button>
```

- Procura no usar las abreviaturas para la etiqueta de apertura de **PHP**, ya que como dice su documentación [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#:%7E:text=Etiquetas%20de%20PHP%20%C2%B6&text=php%20y%20%3F%3E%20%2C%20y%20que,ser%C3%A1%20ignorado%20por%20el%20analizador.):

> PHP también permite la etiqueta de apertura abreviada `<?` (la cual está
> desaconsejada debido a que sólo está disponible si se habilita con la
> directiva **short_open_tag** del fichero de configuración **php.ini**, o si
> PHP se configuró con la opción `--enable-short-tags`).

Lo mas probable es que esto lo tengas desactivado, como viene por defecto.

Puedes notar que me ahorre las comprobaciones de errores en la **consulta** y la **conexión**, pero en la parte de la documentación que te adjunte arriba, esta bien explicado como puedes hacer eso. Si tu consulta es valida y tu conexión no tiene errores esto debería funcionar para ti

Saludos

Comment: Ya edité el código de mi pregunta poniendole la conexion a la bdd

Comment: Me funcionó!!! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Solo que aparece abajo del todo y no dentro de la página, veré como solucionarlo.

Comment: Claro, son cosas que tienes que hacer con **CSS**, mucha suerte amigo..!!